# $_POST value from array of input type="image" array?

Tags: php, arrays, post, dynamic-data

I have a dynamic list of items pulled from a database, where the list contains 0 to N items. Each item is listed in a row in an HTML table with an  submit button. I need to know which of these buttons, specifically, is clicked on $_POST and to obtain the value of that item.

My present approach is to use an array. However, the $_POST value returns all items in the array, not only the item that was clicked. What's more, the array values do not correlate to the values pulled from the database. The same image submit button may be clicked repeatedly and produce different values.

```
<?php
else if (isset($_POST["deleteItem"]))
{   
    foreach ($_POST["deleteItem"] as $value) :
        WishList::Delete($value);
    endforeach; 
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <table id="WishListTable">
<?php
    $wishlist = WishList::GetAllByID($userID);
    foreach ($wishlist as $item)
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $item->Description . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    if ($item->InStock)
    {
        $primaryEmailAlreadyUsed = true;
        echo "In Stock";
    }
    else {
        echo "Out of Stock";
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\"><input type=\"image\" src=\"/images/deleteX.gif\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Delete\" id='" . $iteml->ID . "' name=\"deleteItem[]\" value=\"" . $item->ID . "\" ></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the output of $_POST["deleteItem"] when you press a button?

Comment: "the array values do not correlate to the values pulled from the database" Shouldn't that be addressed first? Why is that?

Comment: does it have to be a button? Could it just be a link? ie. thisscript.php?deleteid=10

Comment: @gmadd: Just as a heads-up, one shouldn't use `GET` to alter data. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol&oldid=429046392#Safe_methods

Comment: Thanks to all for comments. Here are some answers:
1) Sample output: The clicked item is removed from the wishlist table in the database and the page reloads (without the deleted item.
2) Values not correlating: This baffles me. I know the unique ID's for the items displayed.  Instead, my array returns single-digit values that vary. If I comment out the function call and just print_r() the array I can receive different values for the same input item if I click it repeatedly
3) The image button is admittedly cosmetic but I know there is a proper way to do this, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: Thanks @pinkgothic, that's something I should have considered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
name=\"deleteItem[]\"
```

to

```
name=\"deleteItem[" . $item->ID . "]\"
```

On submit, the sole member of deleteItem would be deleteItem[ID]

```
list($deletedItemID) = array_keys($_POST['deleteItem']);
```

Comment: This proved effective and, in retrospect, is embarrassingly obvious. Many thanks, Joe!

Comment: Heads-up: `$deletedItemID = key($_POST['deleteItem']);` is also an option. (I find `list()` to be hard to read in source code, but that's definitely personal opinion.)

Answer (score 1):

i think that the name of your input should be just "deleteItem" instead of "deleteItem[]". Try it. This way you'll get the value of its id in $_POST[ 'deleteItem' ].

Comment: Remember that Internet Explorer doesn't POST back the values of type image inputs. You'll get a $_POST['deleteItem_x'] and $_POST['deleteItem_y']. It might be better to have individual forms for each item with a hidden input containing the id

Comment: @Peter, thanks... the goodness of each browser doing what they want.. :) i tested it in chrome, and i got those 2 fields along with the normal deleteItem.. thanks for pointed that out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more generalized answer to your specific question:

If I have a form like so:

```
<form method = 'post' action = 'action.php'>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit1' value = 'Submit 1'/>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit2' value = 'Submit 2'/>
</form>
```

And in `action.php` I have:

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
        echo($k . ": " . $v . "<br/>")
?>
```

Then if I click the `submit1` button, the output in `action.php` will be:

```
submit1: Submit 1
```

If I click the `submit2` button, the output will be:

```
submit2: Submit 2
```

Instead of having all of the submit images in an array, I would generate a unique name for each of them, either by combining some sort of known ID (preferable) or by appending a counter variable to them.  Then, you can just do a simple `isset($_POST['{button name}'])` check, e.g.:

```
<input type = 'image' src = '...' name = 'deleteItem<?php echo($iteml->ID); ?>'/>
```